# Visual Studio 2008 Class not in Class Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I just added a new MFC class in a VS2008 project and it isn't showing up in the two bars at the top of the editor (just shows Global Scope) and I can't get at the messages and events class wizard stuff.

Is there some way to rebuild the class wizard information so that I don't have to continue adding events and message handlers manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dey7ke4c.aspx) to find out what happened to the Wizard Bar (and class wizard functions). They tell you to look at the properties for a class, there.